# Z library and copyrights

Tags: copyright

I came across a site called "Z Library", in particular, b-ok.org which is "part of Z-libary project".  This site has a free download of a book I really, really, really want.  It has the "look and feel" of a completely legitimate and professional site.  But I take a look at some of the books they have available and I can't believe they are legally free.  Anyone know of copyright issues with "Z Library" sites?  Is this legit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will get the book, and probably won't get caught, but yes, it is illegal.

Comment: Thanks.  Will avoid it, then.